# hibernate hql left join

Tags: hibernate

I have the following query

```
select x.a, x.b, y.a, y.b
from x, y
where y.xid = x.id
```

how do I perform a left join here.

I cannot use the following style so please do not suggest the following.

```
select x.a, x.b, y.a, y.b
from x left join x.y as y
```

Comment: What's exactly the problem? Why can't you use `left join` syntax?

Comment: i updated the hql. x does not have a ref to y but y has an attribute that refers to x. I cannot navigate from x to y.

Comment: can you show us a bit of your mapping? what is exactly the relationship between x and y ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't have a relationship between `x` and `y`, you can't express an outer join between them in HQL.

Thus, you have to create a relationship or use a [native SQL query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html) with left join.

If `y` has a relationship to `x`, you can rewrite left join as right join:

```
select ... from y y right join y.x x
```

Comment: will an outer join work if y has a many to one unidirectional relationship with x. how will the hql be in that case.